# TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular5

I am working on **angular 5** and **onSubmit()** of form I am getting below **error:**

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Below is `onSubmit()` of `login.component.ts` file:

```
onSubmit() {
        this.valid = true;
        const name = this.login.userName;
        sessionStorage.setItem('username', this.login.userName);
        const password = this.login.password;
        console.log(name);
        const user = this.users.filter(currUser => currUser.userName === name && currUser.password === password)[0]; // here I am getting an error!
        if (user) {
            this.isLoggedIn = 'true';
            sessionStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', this.isLoggedIn);
            // this.router.navigate(['/products']);
        } else {
            this.isLoggedIn = 'false';
            sessionStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', this.isLoggedIn);
            this.valid = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's the question? `this.users` is undefined

Comment: Can you provide some more code? There isn't the initialization of `users` so is possible that is undefined for what I can know.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.users
```

Is undefined, make sure you are assigning it elsewhere in the component